Flutter: connecting to a local database
I created a local database and filled it in. Now I want to connect to it. I put it in assets/DB/information.db and pointed to pubspec.yaml. However, the connection does not occur. What could be the reason?
final db_name = "information.db"; 
Future<Database> copyDB() async{  
  var dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
  var path = join(dbPath, db_name);

  var exists = await databaseExists(path);

  if(!exists){
    try{
      await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
    } catch(_){}

    //copy from assets
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join('assets/DB', db_name));
    List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush:true);
  }
  else {
    print('DB already exist');
  }
  return await openDatabase(path,readOnly: true );
}


